How to connect to AWS OpenSearch using OpenSearch.Client NuGet from an AWS Lambda written in C#
I am switching working code from ElasticSearch to OpenSearch.  Replacing the NEST NuGet with OpenSearch.Client went fairly smoothly, and I am able to run the code locally without issue.  When I deploy the code to AWS as a lambda and run it, I get error messages when it attempts to preform the requested Index command.
Things I have tried:
1:
var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(opensearchUrl))
    .EnableDebugMode();

var opensearchClient = new OpenSearchClient(connectionSettings);

await opensearchClient.BulkAsync(bd => bd.IndexMany(itemsToIndex)); //Error occurs here

2:
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(opensearchUrl));
var httpConnection = new AwsSigV4HttpConnection(config.AWSRegion);

var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection)
    .EnableDebugMode();

var opensearchClient = new OpenSearchClient(connectionSettings);

await opensearchClient.BulkAsync(bd => bd.IndexMany(itemsToIndex)); //Error occurs here

3:
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(opensearchUrl));
var awsCredentials = FallbackCredentialsFactory.GetCredentials();
var httpConnection = new AwsSigV4HttpConnection(awsCredentials, config.AWSRegion);

var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection)
    .EnableDebugMode();

var opensearchClient = new OpenSearchClient(connectionSettings);

await opensearchClient.BulkAsync(bd => bd.IndexMany(itemsToIndex)); //Error occurs here

All give similar Exception messages:

Request failed to execute. Call: Status code 403 from: POST /_bulk?pretty=true&error_trace=true

and the DebugInformation messages:

FailureReason: BadResponse while attempting POST on <OpenSearch URL>
...
Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'es'.
...

I have done a lot of searching and have not found anything which explains what is wrong.
Only #1 works when I run locally, when I run #2 and #3 locally I also get the errors.

The problem with 1 was that I was not signing my request.  It worked locally because my IP was white listed in OpenSearch.
The problem with 2 and 3 was that I was passing the AWS region in as a string instead of a RegionEndpoint.  Once I added var awsRegion = RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(config.AWSRegion) and used that for the region, it worked fine.  Of course since the AWS credentials and AWS region are the default, I could use the AwsSigV4HttpConnection constructor without arguments.
Final code:
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri(opensearchUrl));
var httpConnection = new AwsSigV4HttpConnection();

var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, httpConnection)
    .EnableDebugMode();

var opensearchClient = new OpenSearchClient(connectionSettings);

await opensearchClient.BulkAsync(bd => bd.IndexMany(itemsToIndex)); //No Errors!

